# Kivy app exits unexpectedly

Tags: android, python, kivy, qpython

As I'm new to QPython and kivy I encountered a problem that might be very easy to eliminate but I don't know, how to do it.
I have an app which captures QR code and then displays the content of QR code on the screen. The problem is, my app exits right after the code has been scanned. 
Here is my code:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line

from BarQR_seq import Sequence, Barcode_reader

class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        GridLayout.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Widgets())

class Widgets(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.readseq_button = Button(text="Launch")

        self.sequence = ""
        self.seq_id = ""   
        self.readseq_button.bind(on_press=self.run_barcode)
        self.add_widget(self.readseq_button)

    def run_barcode(self, instance):
        bcr = Barcode_reader()
        bcr.capture_barcode()
        seq = Sequence(bcr.barcode)
        seq.get_sequence()
        seq.get_id()
        self.sequence = seq.seq
        self.seq_id = seq.seq_id

    def display_results(self):
        self.seq_label = Label(text="blablabla")
        return self.add_widget(self.seq_label)


class Bar_UI(App):    
    def build(self):
        barcode = Widgets()
        barcode.display_results()
        return barcode


Bar_UI().run()
```

So if you click the button you run the function run_barcode(). This function operates on another class not included in here, but bcr.capture_barcode() just runs the following QPython built-in method:

```
droid = androidhelper.Android()
self.barcode = droid.scanBarcode()
```

And after scanning the code app closes without creating a label.

Do you have any idea what's the issue?

EDIT:
The log says:

```
    [Device information]
f70n_global_com,android:4.4.2,sdk:19

[Recent error information]

[QPython output]
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Nov  2 2015, 01:07:37)
[GCC 4.9 20140827 (prerelease)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
(ImportError: No module named cdrom)
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] Loading kv <./bar_ui.kv>
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] kv <./bar_ui.kv> not found
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame
[DEBUG             ] [WinPygame   ] Set window to fullscreen mode
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Display driver android
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual window size: 480x762
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@66.0 AU@  (CL@)>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 305>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[DEBUG             ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG             ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG             ] [ImagePygame ] Load </data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/glsl/default.png>
[INFO              ] [Support     ] Android install hooks
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[DEBUG             ] [Resource    ] add </system/fonts> in path list
[DEBUG             ] [Resource    ] add </data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/fonts> in path list
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[DEBUG             ] [Base        ] Create provider from android
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO              ] [Android     ] found 17 joystick
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <0>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] discard joystick <0> cause no button
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <1>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <2>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <3>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <4>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <5>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <6>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <7>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <8>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <9>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <10>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <11>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <12>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <13>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <14>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <15>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] create joystick <16>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[DEBUG             ] [Atlas       ] Load </data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/../data/images/defaulttheme.atlas>
[DEBUG             ] [Atlas       ] Need to load 1 images
[DEBUG             ] [Atlas       ] Load </data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/../data/images/defaulttheme-0.png>
[DEBUG             ] [ImagePygame ] Load </data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/../data/images/defaulttheme-0.png>
[INFO              ] [Android     ] Must go into sleep mode, check the app
[INFO              ] [Android     ] App doesn't support pause mode, stop.
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Comment: http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: I have a log - you can see the output from it above in my edit.

Comment: Post all the output.

Comment: I've posted it in edits